# how to write log in TYPO3 backend?

Tags: php, typo3

I would like to debug backend and need to write some logs. I tried the code belowed but it is not working, it doesn't write anything ! Can you help me ?

```
var $logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // desactiver le cache sinoin les FE plugins ne sont pas réactualisé
        // desactivation dans le backend modifie des liens en ajoutant '/no_cache/' devant le lien
        // les liens deviennent inutilisables
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache();
        $this->logger = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogManager')->getLogger(__CLASS__);
        $this->logger->info('Everything went fine.');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following PHP, adapt your extension-key and choose error-level

```
// Log message
$logMessage = 'Everything went fine.';
// Option extension key / module name
$extKey = 'my_extension';
// Error-level: 0 = message, 1 = error (user problem), 2 = System Error (which should not happen), 3 = security notice (admin)
$errorLevel = 0;
// Write sys_log using \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::sysLog
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->simplelog($logMessage, $extKey, $errorLevel);
```

Then you will find your message with timestamp and further informations in sys_log table or in BE modul with name 'Log'.

Comment: Documentation is at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SystemLog/Index.html

Comment: in my development environment $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] is null !

Comment: When you are logged in as be_user at backend?

Comment: I have to be logged in the typo3 admin environment to have $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] not null !

Comment: @jokumer , how to use this when not logged into TYPO3 Backend? $GLOBALS['BE_USER'] is always null in this case.

Comment: @pgampe Documentation 404! Nobody did a 301!

Comment: @ChristianMichael Help improving the docs https://typo3.org/community/teams/documentation/

Comment: Now you properly want to check https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Index.html

Answer (score 3):

Per default LogLevel INFO are not logged. (TYPO3 V8) You have do define a logger for yourself or set the general LogLevel to INFO:

set the general LogLevel to INFO in LocalConfiguration.php:

```
'LOG' => [
    'writerConfiguration' => [
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogLevel::INFO => [
            'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\Writer\\FileWriter' => [
                'logFile'  => 'typo3temp/var/logs/yourlog_info.log',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Or in ext_localconfig.php for my namespace Taywa\Artcollection\Command\ImportCommandController

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['Taywa']['Artcollection']['Command']['ImportCommandController']['writerConfiguration']
= array(
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogLevel::INFO => [
                'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\Writer\\FileWriter' => [
                    'logFile'  => 'typo3temp/var/logs/typo3_artcollection.log',
                ],
            ],
        );
```

Some Documentation about this:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Logging/Configuration/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using does not log to the backend log module, but (by default) to the file `typo3temp/logs/typo3.log` or `typo3temp/var/logs/typo3_*.log`.

It is part of the [new logging framework](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Logging/Index.html#logging).

Comment: hi, I don't have this directory.

Comment: The 'Everything went fine.' string is not written in any of this log files in TYPO3 10.4.5! Only the disabled cache is logged: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 05:33:12 +0100 [WARNING] request="defe4dad6df8a" component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.Controller.TypoScriptFrontendController": $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache() was triggered by /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/typo3projectprovider/Classes/ViewHelpers/Content/FalViewHelper.php on line 31. Caching is disabled!